# onError not implemented error in RxJava2, even though its implemented

Tags: java, android, error-handling, rx-java2, rx-android

So I have a very basic workflow of RxJava observer stream where I request something from retrofit, with successful response I toast successful msg and with error I toast error msg.

The case I am referring below is the error case where I expect error msg from API, I convert it into user readable words and display as `Toast`, As shown below when I use `doOnNext`and `doOnError` method this way it crashes with error mentioned.

I have added `throwExceptionIfFailure` method as well which shows how I convert readable msg and the line where console points to the error.

```
registerNFCTag(body)
                .map(result -> throwExceptionIfFailure(result))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(result -> {
                  toggleLoaders(true);                        
                 appToast(getString(R.string.done_msg) + tagName);
                })
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    Toasty.error(this, throwable.getLocalizedMessage()).show();
                    toggleLoaders(true);
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe();
```

Error If this isnt enough I can post stacktrace as well.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
```

ThrowExceptionIfFailure method.

```
public <T> T throwExceptionIfFailure(T res) {

    Response result = (Response<?>) res;
    if (!result.isSuccessful()) {
        try {
            String msg = result.errorBody().string();
            Log.d(TAG, "throwExceptionIfFailure: "+msg);
            if (result.code() == 401 || result.code() == 403) {
                invalidateToken();
                msg = context.getString(R.string.invalid_credential);
            }
            else if (result.code() == 502)
                msg = context.getString(R.string.server_down);
            else if (result.code() == 422)
                msg = context.getString(R.string.invalid_domain);
            else if (result.code() == 500)
                msg = context.getString(R.string.internal_server_error_500_msg);
            else if (result.code() == 451)
------><>>>>>> expected error msg works well with the case mentioned below with throwable in subscribe itself.
                msg = context.getString(R.string.toast_tag_already_registered_error);

            if (result.code() == 403)
                throw new TokenException();
            else
------>>>>>below line where console points error                  
                throw Exceptions.propagate(new RuntimeException(msg)); 

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
        }
    } else {
        return res;
    }
}
```

But same thing I subscribe this way and it works fine and I see the error msg toasted as expected.

```
registerNFCTag(body)
                .map(result ->throwExceptionIfFailure(result))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(
                        result -> {
                            toggleLoaders(true);
                            appToast(getString(R.string.done_msg) + tagName);
                        }
                        , throwable -> {
                            Toasty.error(this, throwable.getLocalizedMessage()).show();
                            toggleLoaders(true);
                        });
```

Still novice in RxJava2 world so, Help me understand the difference. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Error handling needs to be done in the `subscribe()` as the second argument. If it is not present, then you get a notification that the error is not handled. `doOnError()` is not actually an error handler, despite the implication of its name.

Comment: alright, so in the first case how I should handle error in doOnError() ?

Comment: Why you don't like the working example, that you have posted at the end of your question? What is your question specifically?

Comment: Its good, I use that one only but I just had curiosity to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of RxJava 2.1.9 there are [six overloads](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html) of `subscribe()` method. You have used an overload, that takes no consumers at all. Exception message tells you, that you should use a `subscribe()` overload, that takes error `Consumer`, e.g. [`subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext, Consumer<? super java.lang.Throwable> onError)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-).

`doOnError()` is a *"side-effect"* operator, it has nothing to do with actual subscription.